Using a 12 V DC charger and 8.4 V BMS circuit to power a 5 V load
Link to my original question, which led me to this current question after implementing feedback that I received there.
Charging a BMS and providing power at different voltages
It's clear to me that I fumbled majorly by thinking the BMS included charging. I took the feedback given on the question listed above and spend the weekend doing some more research and trying to implement the TP5100 charging circuit.
This is what I came up with in the end. Feel free to give any additional feedback if I did something that will provoke the magic smoke. (or anything else dumb for that matter :))
The schematic refers to an LDO regulator but in fact it's a standard 7805 regulator datasheet.

BMS with regulator for converting 8.4 V (battery through BMS or through TP5100 when connected to 12 V DC) to 5 V.

TP5100 charging circuit, takes 12 VDC from a barrel jack and provides the BMS with 8.4 V.
The question I have is, is the load going to influence the TP5100? Because I would assume so, but found other people that hooked it up this way.

So in the current situation it is hooked up like in the top diagram, but wouldn't something like the bottom diagram be better? Or, for instance, using a transistor to switch off current between the BMS and the load when 12 V is connected? The regulator can take up to 35 V and convert it to 5 V, so it makes more sense to me to directly supply it with 12 V when connected.

A very warm welcome to the site. Your question and schematic refer to an 'LDO voltage regulator' but the 7805 linear voltage regulator you're using isn't an LDO part, far from it. It has a Vin(min) of 7V for its 5V output. Have corrected this throughout your question but you'll have to edit your schematic to fix that. Also corrected on your other question associated with this one. Thanks.

@TonyM, thanks! Didnt know that, I just researched parts, and this was listed as an LDO. Looks like I've some more learning to do!

You're welcome, glad it helped :-) (a) The 7805 is an old-as-the-hills part from an early family of linear regulator ICs and certainly the linreg that about 90% of the 1970s/1980s-odd logic designers reached for. I remember seeing adverts back then for newer 'low dropout' regulators that were so named in comparison to this hugely used family, and others. (b) You realise that your 7805 with 12Vin and 5Vout will dissipate (7 x Iout) Watts. So if you draw just 100mA, that's 700mW burning in a small package. You'll need a decent heatsink at such currents to stop it getting too hot.

"The question I have is, is the load going to influence the TP5100? Because I would assume so, but found other people that hooked it up this way." Yes, it is. It's vital that Li-ion battery charging is shut off altogether when the battery is full, as overcharging can lead to damage, fire or even explosion. Just because you see others doing something it doesn't mean it's a good idea. Use proper power path management, it's not hard,

There's been a big rise in Li-ion battery fires in the UK because people are making e-bikes and using badly designed or faulty chargers. Don't become another statistic.

The other point to note is that by using a linear regulator to drop 8.4 V to 5 V you're wasting 3.4 V. In other words, roughly 60% of the charge in your battery is going to power the load and the other 40% is going to be wasted as heat. Not a great ratio for these days of a desire for energy efficiency. What is the load? Would it be happy with the output from a buck converter instead of a linear?
